# How do I use just the first value that satisfies a condition in my join?

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I'm trying to think what the most efficient way to do this is, hopefully you can help. I have two tables, one is for Customer Call data (customer calls in to a customer service number), the other is invoice data. They come from different sources so there is no shared PK-FK relationship. Here is some sample data:

**CallData**

| CallId | PhoneNumber | Source | CallDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 555-555-5555 | internet | 2023-11-06 |
| 12346 | 555-666-6666 | referral | 2023-01-01 |
| 12347 | 555-666-6666 | referral | 2023-02-02 |
| 12348 | 555-666-6666 | internet | 2023-05-17 |
| 12349 | 555-777-7777 | referral | 2023-10-31 |
| 12350 | 555-777-7777 | internet | 2023-11-03 |

**Invoice**

| InvoiceId | PhoneNumber | Amount | InvoiceDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 555-555-5555 | 250.56 | 2023-01-01 |
| 22222 | 555-666-6666 | 376.67 | 2023-02-01 |
| 33333 | 555-666-6666 | 761.09 | 2023-06-02 |
| 44444 | 555-666-6666 | 316.23 | 2023-07-03 |
| 55555 | 555-777-7777 | 145.33 | 2023-10-01 |
| 66666 | 555-777-7777 | 986.92 | 2023-11-01 |

I need to be able to join these two together based on the PhoneNumber. But I only care about records where the CallData.Source = 'referral' so that eliminates all but 3 CallData records from above. I then want to sum all the Invoice.Amount values but only if the InvoiceDate is greater than at least ONE of the CallDates.

So consider the CallData records with PhoneNumber 555-666-6666, there are 2 that are referral types and their CallDates are:

- 2023-01-01
- 2023-02-02

And in the Invoice table there are 3 invoices with InvoiceDates of:

- 2023-02-01
- 2023-06-02
- 2023-07-03

All I care about is that all 3 InvoiceDates are AFTER at least one of the matching CallDates (in this case 2023-01-01), so I would sum all three and get 1453.99.

Please let me know if you have any further questions, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use MIN() to get the minimum CallDate per PhoneNumber:

```
SELECT Calls.*, SUM(Invoice.Amount) AS Amount
FROM (
    SELECT PhoneNumber, MIN(CallDate) AS MinCallDate
    FROM CallData
    WHERE Source = 'referral'
    GROUP BY PhoneNumber
) Calls
JOIN Invoice
    ON Invoice.PhoneNumber = Calls.PhoneNumber 
   AND Invoice.InvoiceDate >= Calls.MinCallDate
GROUP BY Calls.PhoneNumber;
```

Output:

| PhoneNumber | MinCallDate | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 555-666-6666 | 2023-01-01 | 1453.99 |
| 555-777-7777 | 2023-10-31 | 986.92 |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-3N2VBHU?hide=2).

Answer (score -1):

You did not specify desired output, so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   CallId,
   CallData.PhoneNumber,
   SUM(Amount) OVER (Partition BY CallId,CallData.PhoneNumber)  as "sum"
   
FROM CallData
INNER JOIN Invoice ON Invoice.PhoneNumber = CallData.PhoneNumber 
                  AND Invoice.InvoiceDate > CallData.CallDate
WHERE CallData.Source = 'referral'
  ;
```

output:

| CallId | PhoneNumber | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12346 | 555-666-6666 | 1454 |
| 12347 | 555-666-6666 | 1077 |
| 12349 | 555-777-7777 | 987 |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/RBn9Iu_E)

90% of this SQL statement is a literal translation of what you wrote in your question into SQL syntax....

or, just by PhoneNumber:

```
SELECT DISTINCT

   CallData.PhoneNumber,
   SUM(Amount) OVER (Partition BY CallData.PhoneNumber)  as "sum"
   
FROM CallData
INNER JOIN Invoice ON Invoice.PhoneNumber = CallData.PhoneNumber 
                  AND Invoice.InvoiceDate > CallData.CallDate
WHERE CallData.Source = 'referral'
  ;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/aSTMw0Pa)

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer on output, that's close but it shouldn't be summing by CallId, just by PhoneNumber...so 555-666-6666 = 1454 and 55-777-7777 = 987

Comment: Looking at PhoneNumber so total for 555-666-6666 will be 2531